# nodejs express local ip address

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, port80

I have a NodeJS app running with express which I'm trying to access at the port 80.

So I have this:

```
app.listen('80', function () {
  console.log('Server started');
});
```

Going to the browser I can acess it by typing "localhost", "127.0.0.1", both with or without :80 as a port.

My question is how can I access it from another computer?

Whenever I type the IP on the browser, it respond as "bad request, invalid hostname"

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct ip?

Comment: You need to expose port 80 on your router

Comment: "Invalid hostname" means that it's not treating it as an i.p. address - it's treating it as a hostname that it needs to look up.  Can you ping the host machine from the other computer?  Also, try accessing via the network i.p. address on the NodeJS machine.

Comment: what os you are using?

Comment: iis was blocking access to port 80. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The Express application should be visible by other computers on the same network.

My best guess is that there is "something" running on your computer that prevents port 80 to expose. Or a conflict with another application that is using port 80 as well. (most unlikely because express cannot run if the port is already in use.).

Comment: iis was blocking access to port 80. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I downvote by mistake. Can you apply some changes so I will remove the downvote?